# $f+g$ is continuous and $f$ and $g$ are everywhere discontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I know that if $f$ and $g$ are both continuous then $f+g$ is continuous. I also know that there are discontinuous functions whose sum is continuous. However, I want to find two functions that are everywhere discontinuous, yet their sum is continuous. I can only come up with examples such as $f(x) = sgn x$,  $g(x) =-sgn x$, but these only have one discontinuity point.

Comment: Take $f$ any everywhere discontinuous and $g=-f$.

Comment: Try Dirchilet type functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take

$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            1 & \quad x \in \Bbb Q \\
            0 & \quad x \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

and

$$
g(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
           0 & \quad x \in \Bbb Q \\
            1 & \quad x \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Answer (score 8):

You only need to find a function $f$ that's discontinuous everywhere, since then you can take $g=-f$ and clearly $f+g=0$ will be continous.

Such a function can be found by taking $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is a rational number, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

To generate infinitely many examples, take $g = h - f$, where $h$ is a continuous function.